# Making a group by query in Django

Tags: django, django-models

Here is my model:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Skill(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % self.name

class AppForm(models.Model):
    creation_date = models.DateField(db_index=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ...
    preferred_skill = models.ManyToManyField(Skill,db_index=True)
    preferred_skill_other = models.CharField(max_length=250,default='')
    ...
```

I would like to make the following query:

```
sqlite> SELECT "app_form_appform_preferred_skill"."skill_id",
        COUNT("app_form_appform"."id")
        FROM "app_form_appform"
        INNER JOIN "app_form_appform_preferred_skill"
        ON ("app_form_appform"."id" = "app_form_appform_preferred_skill"."appform_id")
        GROUP BY "app_form_appform_preferred_skill"."skill_id";
```

NOTE: app_form_appform_preferred_skill is a table created by django due to the many-to-many relationship specified in the model.

Can this query be made using just the django ORM? I tried to use aggregate, but I could not get it to do what this query does, the difficulty for me is in getting the GROUP BY clause using the ORM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that by using `Count` along with [`.annotate()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#annotate):

```
>>> from django.db.models import Count
>>> skills = Skill.objects.annotate(form_count=Count("appform"))
```

You can get the total count of forms tied to each Skill instance:

```
>>> skills[0].form_count
```

You can use [`.values()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values) to represent each instance as a dictionary containing only `id` and `form_count`:

```
>>> skills.values("id", "form_count")
<QuerySet [{'id': 1, 'form_count': 2}, {'id': 2, 'form_count': 3}, ...>
```